# JavaScript CSS3 Animation dynamically reset the style tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Ok so I have a javascript object that in the end a user sets the object properties and that is what we are going to use. My problem is I can't seem to erase the `webkit-animation` from the style tag... I've tried

```
ele.style.webkitAnimation = null;
ele.style.webkitAnimation = "";
```

Neither work, here is the line I am using to actually set the `webkitAnimation`

```
 newImage.style.webkitAnimation= 
                     options.animation + " " 
                     + options.animationSpeed+"s" + " " 
                     + options.animationEffect + " " 
                     + ((options.speed / 1000) - options.animationSpeed)+"s";
```

Which then comes out something like this:

```
 -webkit-animation: spinner 1s ease-in 1.5s;
```

I need it to be deleted each time I set it to be deleted. Anyone have a suggestion to how to go about this, or even a better way to set the `webkitAnimation`? I need to be able to set the duration timing function and the delay, as well as the animation name dynamically.

Any questions please ask before a downvote and I will get you your information... Thanks guys

Comment: Since I am using this right outside a for loop and the forloop ats z-indexing I just added `ele.removeAttribute('style');` and that worked fine for now.

Comment: Any way you can provide a live example? Removing animations is finicky sometimes